# Store c_str() as char *

Tags: c++, string, constants, c-str

I'm trying to use the function with the following declaration:
`extern int stem(struct stemmer * z, char * b, int k)1`

I'm trying to pass a C++ string to it, so I thought I'd use the `c_str()` function. It returns `const char *`. When I try to pass it to the `stem()` function, I get this error: `error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]`.

How can I store the result of c_str() such that I can use it with the `stem` function?

Here is the code I'm running:

```
    struct stemmer * z = create_stemmer();
    char * b = s.c_str();
    int res = stem(z, b, s.length()); //this doesn't work
    free_stemmer(z);
    return s.substr(0,res);
```

Comment: You can use `&s[0]` in C++11.

Comment: You mean in place of b?

Comment: `const char* mstr=""; char* str=const_cast<char*>(mstr);`

Comment: Does `stem` modify the string? If so, why are you trying to pass `const char*` to it? If not, why did you declare the parameter `char *`?

Comment: `char * b = s.c_str();` this should fail, possibly a typo in snippet? ...and can you please add a few words about how your `stem()` function works?

Comment: Why should it fail? Here is the function header of c_str(): `const char* c_str() const noexcept;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `c_str()` returns a buffer that can not be modified (`const`), while `stem()` may modify the buffer you pass in (not `const`). You should make a copy of the result of `c_str()` to get a modifiable buffer.

The page http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ has more information on the C++ 98 and 11 versions. They suggest replacing `char * b = s.c_str();` with the following:

```
char * b = new char [s.length()+1];
std::strcpy (b, s.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to remove constness of a string returned by `c_str()`:

```
char * b = s.c_str();
```

but you can pass an address of `std::string`'s internal buffer directly:

```
int res = stem(z, static_cast<char*>(&s[0]), s.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

If `stem()` is going to modify the string, then make a copy of it:

```
char * scpy= strdup( s.c_str()) ;
int res = stem(z, scpy, strlen( scpy)); 
free( scpy) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use const_cast:

```
int res = stem(z, const_cast<char*>(s.c_str()), s.length()+1);
free_stemmer(z);
return s.substr(0,res);
```

Note the length+1 expression which might (or might not) be needed. C-style strings (char*) have an additional null terminator (zero byte, equivalent "\0") at the end. Your stem function may (or may not) expect a null terminator at the end of the string - try both variants.

Note also that "stem" function should not try to modify the string, otherwise bad things may happen (warning based on @David Heffernan's comment)

Comment: if stem modifies the c string this is undefined behaviour and will potentially causes bugs or crashes the application

Answer (score 0):

```
.c_str()
```

Just returns a pointer to the data, I would update the stem function to accept a `'const char*'` unless you are wanting to modify the data in the string, in that case you should pass it as a new string object.

If you can't edit the stem function you can cast it:

```
int res = stem(z, const_cast<char*>(s.c_str()), s.length());
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not good to do this, but nothing stops you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void foo(char *ch)
{
  ch[0] = 'B';
}

int main()
{
  string str = "helo world";

  char *ch = const_cast<char *>(str.c_str());

  foo(ch);

  // Belo world
  cout << str << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @downvoter? please why at least?  I know it's a bad idea, but at least this works if you sure you don't mess up with `char *ch`.

Comment: My guess: Because he thought what you're doing is a bad idea.

Comment: Sure, but the very start of the comment stated that.

Comment: Please downvoter, some comments and suggestion are very much appreciated.  Or just follow suit to donwvote?