# How can I copy the contents of string to an array of char c++?

Tags: c++

So I have this issue

```
//This holds 5 messages submitted prev by the user, temporarily stored
string arrayOfMessages[5];
```

lets say

```
arrayOfMessages[0]="This is my message"//The message in the first position.
```

I need to copy `arrayOfMessages[0]` to an array of `char` like this one;

```
char message [20];
```

I tried using `strcpy(message,arrayOfMessages[0])` but I get this error :

```
error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'const char*'|
```

Anyone know how I can accomplish this or if I'm doing something wrong, I cant set the string to be a const char bc the message was imputed prev by the user so it changes every time you run the program thus cannot be a constant variable.

Comment: use `std::string::c_str()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store c\_str() as char \*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305611/store-c-str-as-char)

Comment: `c_str()` is designed for this. But why do you need to copy, and what are you going to do if the source string is too long are the important questions.

Comment: I´m no sure I understand how to use c_str(), mainly cus  it requires strcpy and my variables cannot be const * so it wont copy

Comment: @Mansoor im afraid it doesn´t,

Comment: Read the first answer more closely, `strcpy(message,arrayOfMessages[0].c_str())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it

By using the c_str() function of the string class

```
string message = "This is my message";
const char *arr;
arr = message.c_str();
```

By copying all the characters from the string to the char array

```
string message = "This is my message";
char arr[200];
for(int i = 0; i < 200 && message[i] != '\0'; i++){
    arr[i] = message[i];
}
```

Be careful with the array sizes if you use the second approach.
You can also make it a function in order to make it easier to use

```
 void copyFromStringToArr(char* arr, string str, int arrSize){
     for(int i = 0; i<arrSize && str[i] != '\0'; i++){
         arr[i] = str[i];
     }
 }
```

So in your case you can just call the function like this:

```
copyFromStringToArr(message,arrayOfMessages[0],20);
```

Also I am sure there are many more ways to do it but these are the ones I would use.

Comment: I cant use the either bc i have to the same for 5 messages i cant use const char * in the variable. And the second option wonk work bc the string is located in an array thus i cant no use message [i] to copy , this is a one dimensional array of 5 strings

Comment: You can still use the [i] you just have to do it like this for example: `arrayOfMessages[0][i]`. Because array of strings can be treated like a 2D array

Answer (score 0):

To copy the contents of `std::string` into a `char[]`, use `c_str()`:

```
std::string str = "hello";

char copy[20];
strcpy(copy, str.c_str());
```

But the datatype of `copy` must be only `char*` and not `const char*`. If you want to assign it to a `const char*`, then you can use direct assignment:

```
std::string str = "hello";
const char *copy = str.c_str();
```